# Using pandas fillna in the init function of a class python

Tags: python, pandas, class

I want to define a class that has as super the pd.DataFrame object as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

class my_data_frame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, index, columns):
        super(my_data_frame,self).__init__(index = index, columns = columns)
        self = self.fillna(0)
        print('init',self)

df = my_data_frame([1,2,3],['a','b','c'])
print('first', df)
```

This will print the output

```
init    a  b  c
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0
3  0  0  0
first      a    b    c
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

So the question is why does the fillna function on line 5 doesn't really work. Since printing it from the init function seems to work, but in the command line it doesn't.

Comment: `self = self.fillna(0)` simply assigns a new Dataframe to the local variable `self`, which is then discarded once the method terminates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Allen already show's you a way to do this but I'll add some additional commentary.

1. Read this link on [**subclassing pandas objects**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures)
2. I'd simplify the call to `super` to avoid the trouble of `fillna`
3. Here's how I'd use link in item 1.

   a. I created a class that passes parameters straight through to the DataFrame constructor.
   b. I look to see if `data` was passed and if not, I set it equal to zero.
   c. I create an attribute (@property) that defines what the constructor is.  This is what tells pandas to use when creating those new copies.  Because I defined a subclass that passes all arguments straight through, this should be pretty clean.
   d. I defined a function that accomplishes the intent of your initializer.

---

```
import pandas as pd

class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if len(args) == 0:
            kwargs.setdefault('data', 0)

        super(MyDataFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MyDataFrame

def my_data_frame(index, columns):
    return MyDataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
```

**Demo**

```
mdf = my_data_frame([1,4,3],['a','b','c'])
mdf

   a  b  c
1  0  0  0
4  0  0  0
3  0  0  0
```

---

```
mdf2 = mdf[['a', 'c']]
mdf2

   a  c
1  0  0
4  0  0
3  0  0
```

---

```
type(mdf2)

__main__.MyDataFrame
```

Answer (score 1):

Use inplace = True works for some reason:

```
class my_data_frame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, index, columns):
        super(my_data_frame,self).__init__(index = index, columns = columns)
        self.fillna(0, inplace=True)
        print('init',self)


my_data_frame([1,4,3],['a','b','c'])
init    a  b  c
1  0  0  0
4  0  0  0
3  0  0  0
Out[557]: 
   a  b  c
1  0  0  0
4  0  0  0
3  0  0  0
```

I think it has something to do with the assignment. When you use self=, it creates a new DataFrame and assigned to your custom class but the super class was not updated.

Comment: It's because `self = self.fillna(0)` simply assigns a new Dataframe o the local variable `self`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's really tempting to inherit from a dataframe, but don't. This is one of many problems that you'll run into. Probably the most common one is that lots of functions return "fresh" dataframes. So you use a method on your new_dataframe and it will return a normal dataframe.

Also, you example doesn't work like that because once you assign to self python will treat it as a local variable.